# Touchpad on keyboard not recognizing taps

Tags: windows-7, touchpad

I have a Compaq Presario cq56 and my touchpad is not working properly.

I can move my cursor around the screen, but when I want to click on a program it won't do so.

To get to my programs I have to left click the button at the bottom of the touch pad.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Control Panel**, then **Mouse**, then click the **Device Settings** tab and you should see your touch pad as one of the devices. Make sure your touch pad is highlighted and click the **Settings** button and you will see Tapping as one of the choices. You can enable it from there.